# How do I specify the "before-the loop" code when using "perl -ne"?

Tags: perl, command-line

How do I specify the "before-the loop" code when using "perl -ne", without resorting to either BEGIN/END blocks or replacing "-n" with actually spelled-out `while` loop?

To explain in detail:

Say, I have the following Perl code:

```
use MyModule;
SETUP_CODE;
while (<>) {
    LOOP_CODE;
}
FINAL_CODE;
```

How can I replace that with a one-liner using `perl -ne`?

Of course, the loop part is handled by the `-n` itself, while the `FINAL_CODE` can be done using a trick of adding "`} { FINAL_CODE`" at the end; whereas the `use` statement can be handled via "`-M`" parameter.

So, if we had no `SETUP_CODE` before the loop, I could write the following:

```
perl -MMyModule -ne 'LOOP_CODE } { FINAL_CODE'
```

But, how can we insert `SETUP_CODE` here?

The only idea I have is to try to add it after the loop via a `BEGIN{}` block, ala

```
perl -MMyModule -ne 'LOOP_CODE } BEGIN { SETUP_CODE } { FINAL_CODE'
```

But this seems at best hacky.

**Any other solution?**

Just to be clear - I *already know* I can do this by either spelling out the `while` loop instead of using "-n" or by using BEGIN/END blocks (and might even agree that from certain points of view, doing "while" is probably better).

What I'm interested in is whether there is a **different** solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sneak your extra code into the `-M` option

```
perl -M'Module;SETUP CODE' -ne 'LOOP CODE'
```

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -M'MyModule;$SETUP=1' -ne '$LOOP=1}{$FINAL=1'
use MyModule;
$SETUP = 1;
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    $LOOP = 1;
}
{
    $FINAL = 1;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 6):

Write `BEGIN` and `END` blocks without ceremony:

```
$ perl -lne 'BEGIN { print "hi" }
             print if /gbacon/;
             END { print "bye" }' /etc/passwd
hi
gbacon:x:700:700:Greg Bacon,,,:/home/gbacon:/bin/bash
bye
```

Comment: @Greg - sorry, this doesn't answer my question of how to do this WITHOUT a `BEGIN` block. This being Perl, I'm almost certain there oughtta be TIMTOWODI

Comment: @DVK Why don't you want to use a `BEGIN` block?

Comment: @DVK: Then use an `INIT{}` block.  May I `Acme::` it?

Comment: @Greg - I didn't say I don't want to use it. I'm just intellectually curious to see if I can do it some other way because BEGIN looks *mildly* hacky to me and might have unforeseen consequences.

Comment: BEGIN blocks are not hacky in the least.  They're for exactly this kind of situation.

Comment: @DVK: The crud of sneaking stuff in post-loop with stuff that isn’t syntactically valid otherwise is what I call tacky. I don’t see what’s wrong with an `INIT{}`, nor do I see what you are nervous about vis-à-vis `BEGIN{}`, either. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Sean - to clarify, it's not the begin block that's hacky. It's changing the semantics of the original code by putting the logic that was NOT in the BEGIN block into the BEGIN block. It works (at least in a simple case like this), but has a mild smell to me. And again to clarify, the reason I want other options is mostly curiocity, NOT my opinion of BEGIN solution

Comment: @tchrist - one thing that is slightly worrisome is whether "-M" would precede the BEGIN block or not. I have a feeling the precedence would be correct (e.g. BEGIN block will follow the `use`), but don't have an x-term in front of me at the moment to verify

Comment: @tchrist - as for post-loop, it seems to be a well accepted idiom, though I agree that it has a bit of a weird smell style-wise (like a lot of one-liner solutions). Now, replacing BEGIN with INIT block, that idea seems good since it eliminates my concerns about semantics changes to at least some degree.

Comment: @DVK: Things happen in order, including out-of-order things.    How can you live without somewhere to type?

Comment: @DVK: If that grossery’s a “well-accepted idiom”, it’s one that makes `select((select(FH),$|=1)[0]` smell like pretty purple posies.  I think it smells.

Comment: Anything *other* than BEGIN would be hacky to the point of utter stupidity.

Comment: @DVK: in agreement with hobbs.  also, not sure what advantage you see in INIT over BEGIN?  if you really want the original code semantics, just do `-e 'use MyModule;' -e 'SETUP_CODE;' -e 'while (<>) {' -e 'LOOP_CODE();' -e '}' -e 'FINAL_CODE();'`

Comment: @ysth: You can do things in an `INIT{}` which you cannot do in a `BEGIN{}`.  **And *vice versa* too**.

Comment: @tchrist: select(select(FH)) is a useful idiom for initializing `*FH{IO}`, by the way

Answer (score 2):

Put your extra code in a module and use `‑M`.  That’ll run before the loop.

You might even be able to sneak something in via `$ENV{PERL5OPT}`, although the switches are pretty limited; no `‑e` or `‑E`, for example.

I suppose you could do something outrageous with `$ENV{PERL_ENCODING}` too, if you really wanted to.

This is all `Acme::` territory.  *Please* don’t. ☹

**EDIT:** The *only* solution I much like is the very uncreative and completely straightforward `INIT{}`.

Comment: Hmm... Putting it into an extra module kinda defeats the whole point and spirit of having a "-ne" one-liner, but I gotta give points on originality. Why didn't you put in your `INIT{}` suggestion? I like it the best so far

Comment: @DVK: `INIT{@ARGV="<&DATA" if !@ARGV}` is one you ain’t gonna be doin’ in a `BEGIN{}`, since the compiler won’t have gotten there yet.

Comment: @DVK: I should point out that sometimes you won’t get an `INIT{}` block to run; *e.g.* if you’re in a string `eval` after the main compilation phase.  `UNITCHECK{}` still works, though.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the -n and add `while (<>) {` ... `}`.
What? It's shorter and more straightforward than the `BEGIN` thing.

Comment: while it's a valid point on the style merits, I already know that and was explicitly interested to a technical solution to this specific problem. I will update the question to clarify

Comment: I don’t know I agree.  I certainly have programs whose `#!` line has a `‑n` or `‑p` in it. Perfectly natural.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is some obscure way to achieve this with `-ne`, but yeah, it is much easer just to use `perl -e` and code in the `while(<>)` yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can have multiple -e switches on the command line.

Assuming test contains

```
1
2
3
4

perl -e '$a=5;' -ne '$b+=$_ + $a}{print "$b\n"' test
```

will print 30.

Comment: But they all get put into the implicit loop that you can from `‑n` or `‑p`, so that’s no help.

Comment: Oops.  Nevermind.  I ran perl -MO=Deparse on that and found that the $a=5 was added inside the while loop.

Comment: Agreed. You'd see that your first `-e` actually turns into `-ne` by having the first code snippet say `$a+=1;` and printing `$a` at the end together with `$b` - that way you'd see it got assigned the # of lines instead of 1... oh yeah, or by running Deparse :)